# Are those 2 theorems saying the same idea?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

This theorem is from Rudin 3rd edition:

> [image]

But I want to prove a theorem by the theorems in Royden only. and the most similar theorem in Royden I can see (from my point of view ) is:

[image]

Am I correct, those two theorems are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are similar, but not the same. The first theorem sandwiches $f$ between semicontinuous functions, while the second theorem sandwiches $f$ between simple functions.

Comment: which theorem includes the other ?

Comment: I don't think that one includes the other. Not every semicontinuous function is simple, and not every simple function is either upper or lower semicontinuous.